# Default app for file type

Tags: settings, files, default-applications

I have a Nokia 6.1 with Android 10 (Android One).

I was trying to download my account statement in Revolut app. It gives me an option to select either PDF or Excel (CSV) format to download. But instead of downloading it opens PDF in Android's default PDF viewer, and for CSV it attaches it to a new e-mail in Gmail app instead. I assume this happens because of file associations, but I can't find an option to configure them.

My problem is that I don't want my account statement coming straight through Google. It's just my personal preference to avoid feeding Google sensitive data directly.

Is it a problem with Revolut or Android? If it's Android, can I configure behavior for file types to open CSV in a different app?

Comment: See [these answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22better+open+with%22)

Comment: I've checked the app, it didn't change anything.

Comment: How a file handles a file (for opening or downloading) totally depends on the app developer. Usually apps fire an *implicit intent* with details of the file and the action the app wants to perform on it. Android then resolves this intent by matching its details with all installed apps and creates a list of apps that can handle the file type and action. If there are more than 1 apps available, Android pops up an option list where user can select the desired app (and also set it as default for future use). If only one app is found, an explicit intent is forwarded to that app from OS.

Comment: So at OS level usually there is nothing you can do except clearing defaults. Apps like Better Open With intercept all intents from all apps by claiming that they can handle every file type and every action. Then they provide options to the user what they want to do with it. You can chack logcat (ResolverActivity in particular) while opening PDF or CSV file to better understand how the app opens them. This can lead to a solution.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I've tried reaching out to the company and now I'm waiting for the response. If they don't respond I'll try to debug this myself